# Trying to scrape HTML table and convert into dataframe in Python. Code not working correctly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the coinmarketcap website for its historical daily data (in a HTML table), but not getting the correct result.  Below is the code.  The code only returns the last row of the table.  I'm doing something wrong with the loop...any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data') 

soup = BeautifulSoup(data._content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

#the table has 7 columns, about 30 rows
new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,7), index = [0]) 

row_marker = 0
for row in table.find_all('tr'):    
    column_marker = 0
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    for column in columns:
        new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
        column_marker += 1
print (new_table.head())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

```
url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data'

df = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=[0])[0]
print (df.head())
        Date    Open    High     Low   Close     Volume   Market Cap
0 2017-11-09  308.64  329.45  307.06  320.88  893250000  29509000000
1 2017-11-08  294.27  318.70  293.10  309.07  967956000  28128700000
2 2017-11-07  298.57  304.84  290.77  294.66  540766000  28533300000
3 2017-11-06  296.43  305.42  293.72  298.89  579359000  28322700000
4 2017-11-05  300.04  301.37  295.12  296.26  337658000  28661500000
```